# How to add a scheduled task with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a small console application that is installed along my (bigger) application. The setup is created with Inno Setup, which works very nice.

I want Inno Setup to add one or more tasks to the windows scheduler (that starts the console app). Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply add the [`task scheduler command line`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx) entries to the [`[Run]`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_runsection.htm) section of your script. The entries in that section are executed after the program is successfully installed.

Comment: Thank you very much TLama! I didn't know it would be that simple. This is the line i added to the Inno script: [Run] Filename:  schtasks.exe; Parameters:" /create /tn "ESS pushdata" /tr {app}\pushdata.exe /sc daily "

Answer (score 14):

To give a more concrete example than the @TLama's answer:

For example, to schedule a task to run your application with some parameter every hour, use:

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks"; \
    Parameters: "/Create /F /SC HOURLY /TN ""My Task"" /TR ""'{app}\MyProg.exe' par1"""; \
    Flags: runhidden
```

Note:

- the [double double-quotes](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params) around the command-line (and task name) and single quotes around the path to the application;
- the `/F` switch to overwrite any existing task with the same name (important for re-installations/upgrades).

See a full documentation for the [`schtasks.exe` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks) and the [`[Run]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection).

---

When you want to debug a non-working task creation, start the `schtasks` with the `cmd.exe /K` (and of course, remove the `runhidden` flag):

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; \
    Parameters: "/K schtasks /F /Create /SC HOURLY /TN ""My Task"" /TR ""'{app}\MyProg.exe' par1""";
```

This way the console window with an error message is preserved.

See [Debugging non-working batch file or command executed from Inno Setup installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37324386/850848).

---

For uninstalling, see
[Delete Task Scheduler task at Uninstall?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52185023/850848)