# Inno Setup install on a schedule or at a specific time

Tags: inno-setup

I am aware that I could use Task Scheduler to schedule an unattended installation. However, is it possible to run the Setup, select options and then have it start the install process at a set time or with a countdown timer? If possible, how could this functionality be created?

Comment: I don't understand very well why you would want to do this. Can you provide a usage scenario, or the reason you want to do this ? It would help us answer your question better.

Comment: In my use case this would be a package to run some updates on a database which cannot be run whilst the system is in use. Therefore, creating an option where the customer can run the package and simply leave it to install at a certain time when no-one is using the system is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need two installers.

1. An actual installer.
2. A wrapper installer that will just store/install the actual installer somewhere and schedule a task to run the actual installer at a certain time.

It can actually be just one installer (binary), running with a different set of (command-line) arguments. But that's a bit more difficult to implement.

See also [How to add a scheduled task with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12250151/850848)

---

Or consider using [`RunOnce` registry key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys) to schedule the upgrade for the next login (if that helps).

Comment: So, the solution would be to create a Scheduled Task still, but to do it with a second installer?

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest approach. Or use `RunOnce`, see my edit.