# Debugging non-working batch file or command executed from Inno Setup installer

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

I am trying to install Tomcat as a service on Windows 10 via command line using Inno Setup but I am running into problems currently this is my syntax.

```
[Run] 
Filename: net.exe; Flags: runascurrentuser; parameters: "user elt_user TrackFox38# /add"

; installs tomcat makes it run as a service NOTE THAT IN INNO THIS IS A SINGLE LINE
Filename: {src}\..\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\bin\service.bat; Flags: runascurrentuser; parameters: "tomcat7 //IS//Tomcat7 --DisplayName='Apache_Tomcat_7' ^ --Install='C:\Program Files\Tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe' --Jvm=auto ^ --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm ^ --StartClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams=start ^ --StopClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopParams=stop"
```

The weird thing is that it works when I manually paste it into command line.  At first I thought it was a permissions issue but the fact that the `net.exe` command works and Tomcat doesn't calls that into question.  Also I have privileges required set to admin and the app needs admin privileges to start the installer so I don't think its a user issue.  I'm new to Inno Setup and a bit stuck here.

Debug output:

```
[09:18:54.770] Filename: C:\program\Output\..\apache-tomcat-   7.0.69\bin\service.bat 
[09:18:54.771] Parameters: tomcat7 //IS//Tomcat7 --DisplayName='Apache_Tomcat_7' ^ --Install='C:\Program Files\Tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe' --Jvm=auto ^ --StartMode=jvm --StopMode=jvm ^ --StartClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams=start ^ --StopClass=org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopParams=stop 
[09:18:54.867] Process exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute a batch file (or any command), its results (or errors) are either not visible at all (particularly when `runhidden` flag is used) or disappear that quickly that you cannot read them.

In that case, run the command explicitly via `cmd.exe` (Inno Setup does it implicitly on its own when running batch files), but this time with `/K` switch instead of a more common `/C` switch. The `/K` switch ensures that a console window does not close on its own. And of course, remove the `runhidden` flag.

So instead of:

```
[Run] 
Filename: {app}\setup.bat; Parameters: "arguments"
```

or an equivalent:

```
[Run] 
Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/C """"{app}\setup.bat"" arguments"""
```

Use:

```
[Run] 
Filename: {cmd}; Parameters: "/K """"{app}\setup.bat"" arguments"""
```

Then the console window stays after the `setup.bat` finishes and you can see eventual errors.

If the batch file starts with common `@echo off` command that hides the commands being executed, temporarily commenting out this line with `rem` will help debugging too.

[image]

For quoting of arguments in cmd command-line, see:
[Correct quoting for cmd.exe for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12891383/850848)