# How can I keep console window after executing a command in Inno Setup

Tags: cmd, installation, inno-setup

I have a script like:

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C "" sqlcmd -S {code:ServerName}  -U {code:UserLOG} """ ; \
    Flags: nowait    skipifsilent
```

How can I keep the console window until user sees it?

I need to show the user the result of the operation on that console window.

Comment: If you want to output the result to **file** or something else, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136770/how-to-get-an-output-of-an-execed-program-in-inno-setup) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `cmd /K`... instead of `cmd /C`... your install script opens a new console (inside the console window) which doesn't close automatically and must be closed by the user. Thus, you're able to read the output.

You can find the full list of parameters at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd

Comment: That's a [good simple approach for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37324386/850848). But not a good idea for end-user-experience.

Answer (score 3):

Use `pause` Windows command, like:

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C ""sqlcmd ... & pause"""; Flags: nowait skipifsilent
```

---

Note that you actually do not need to run `sqlcmd` via `cmd.exe` (`{cmd}`). You can run it directly. But to combine the `sqlcmd` with the `pause`, you need the `cmd.exe`.

---

If the command itself needs spaces (like if you need to use `{app}\MyProg.exe`), use this syntax:

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C """"{app}\MyProg.exe"" ... & pause"""; ...
```