# How to run a command with path including spaces (bundled JRE) when using AfterInstall with Inno Setup

Tags: java, cmd, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am installing a Java program as an exe with a bundled JRE folder. I can't get the setup to successfully call the bundled `java.exe` with my application.

So my laptop has Java installed already so the following worked:

```
[Files]
Source: "jre\*"; DestDir: "{app}\jre"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "build\launch4j\Application Lite.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; \
    AfterInstall: MyAfterInstall
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure MyAfterInstall();
var ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    Exec(
        'cmd.exe',
        '/c java -cp ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\Application Lite.exe')) +
            ' com.examplesoftware.applicationlite.support.hibernateSupport',
        '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

Where `{app}` is by default `c:\Example Software\Application Lite`.

The following does not work when I try use the bundled JRE:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure MyAfterInstall();
var ResultCode: Integer;
begin
    Exec(
        'cmd.exe',
        '/k ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\jre\bin\java.exe')) +
            ' -cp ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\Application Lite.exe')) +
            ' com.examplesoftware.applicationlite.support.hibernateSupport',
        '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
end;
```

I get the error:

> 'c:\Example' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

If I use `echo` with the code like this:

```pascal
Exec(
    'cmd.exe',
    '/k echo ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\jre\bin\java.exe')) +
        ' -cp ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\Application Lite.exe')) +
        ' com.examplesoftware.applicationlite.support.hibernateSupport',
    '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

and copy the command it works. I don't understand why it is breaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `cmd`, it only makes it more complicated. This should work:

```pascal
Exec(
  ExpandConstant('{app}\jre\bin\java.exe'),
  '-cp ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\Application Lite.exe')) + 
    ' com.examplesoftware.applicationlite.support.hibernateSupport',
  '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```

---

Had it not work and you have wanted to [debug the command with the `cmd /k`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37324386/850848), you need to [wrap whole command to double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6376113/850848):

```pascal
Exec(
  'cmd.exe',
  '/k "' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\jre\bin\java.exe')) +
    ' -cp ' + AddQuotes(ExpandConstant('{app}\Application Lite.exe')) +
    ' com.examplesoftware.applicationlite.support.hibernateSupport"',
  '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode);
```