# Trying to do silent install using inno setup for MySQL Server 5.1 , but MySQL server was not starting

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

I have tried following code to silent install the MySQL but Script is not starting the SQL Server. below are the code

**Filename: net.exe; Parameters:start MySQL; StatusMsg: Starting the service MySQL; Description: Starting the service mysql; Flags: runhidden**

--> it is returning the value as 2 .

Please correct where i'm doing mistake.

```
[Files]
Source: "Sample.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

;MYSQL Install
Source: "mysql-5.1.73-winx64.msi"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: deleteafterinstall; Permissions: everyone-full; Check: MySQLIsNotInstalled
; AfterInstall: InstallMySQL


[Run]
Filename: msiexec.exe; Parameters:"/i ""{app}\mysql-5.1.73-winx64.msi"" /qn INSTALLDIR=""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\"" "; WorkingDir:{app}; StatusMsg:"Installing the mysql package"; Flags: runhidden;
Filename: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld.exe; Parameters:--install MySQL --port=3306;StatusMsg: Installation the service MySQL;Description: Installation the service mysql; Flags: runhidden 
Filename: net.exe; Parameters:start MySQL; StatusMsg: Starting the service MySQL; Description: Starting the service mysql; Flags: runhidden
Filename: "{sys}\netsh.exe"; Parameters: firewall add portopening TCP 3306 MySQL; StatusMsg: "Enregistrement par défaut port MySQL ..."; Flags: runhidden; MinVersion: 0,5.01.2600sp2
;Filename: "{sys}\netsh.exe"; Parameters: "firewall set service type = fileandprint mode = enable"; StatusMsg: "Activation du partage de fichier et d'imprimante ..."; Flags: runhidden; MinVersion: 0,5.01.2600sp2
```

Comment: What do you mean "it was not working?"  What part isn't working?  What errors are you getting?  You need to give a lot more information.

Comment: See [Debugging non-working batch file or command executed from Inno Setup installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37324386/850848).

Comment: Filename: net.exe; Parameters:start MySQL; StatusMsg: Starting the service MySQL; Description: Starting the service mysql; Flags: runhidden  @mirtheil  it is returning the value as 2. when i manually try to start the server it is not starting as well