# Inno Setup: How to remove Abort from regserver error?

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I was wondering, if there is a way to make the message box displayed, when occurs an error from `regserver` flag in `Files` section, to show only *Retry* and *Ignore* option, not the *Abort* one.

I know there's a flag `noregerror`. I don't want to not show the error. I want to show it, but with only two options.

Sometimes when the error is displayed while trying to register an OCX/DLL, when the user clicks in *Retry*, it works in the second time. If the user clicks in *Cancel*, the installer rollbacks everything, deleting the files from my update program.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to customize those buttons.

But you can implement the registration in code using [`RegisterServer`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_registerserver). Then you can handle errors any way you like. You can actually even retry the registration automatically, what you seem to actually want to do.

Though it's not easy to implement *Retry/Ignore* message box. The below code uses simple *Yes/No*.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyDll.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: RegServer

[Code]

procedure RegServer;
var
  FileName: string;
  Message: string;
  Retry: Boolean;
begin
  repeat
    Retry := False;
    FileName := ExpandConstant(CurrentFilename);
    try
      { First argument indicates if DLL is 64-bit }
      RegisterServer(False, FileName, True);
    except
      Message :=
        FileName + #13#10#13#10 +
        FmtMessage(SetupMessage(msgErrorRegisterServer), [AddPeriod(GetExceptionMessage)]) +
          #13#10#13#10 +
        'Do you want to retry registration? ' +
        'Click Yes to try again or No to proceed anyway (not recommended).';
      Retry := (MsgBox(Message, mbError, MB_YESNO) = IDYES);
    end;
  until (not Retry);
end;
```

[image: Registration error]

Comment: Thanks Martin, you're always helping me out. That's exactly what I wish to do.