# Delete Task Scheduler task at Uninstall?

Tags: inno-setup, windows-task-scheduler

My installed app creates a Task Scheduler task at run-time. This Task Scheduler task runs one of my installed apps at Windows log on. So I need to delete this Task Scheduler task at uninstall. Is the Inno Setup-Uninstaller able to do this?

OS: Win 7/8/10 x64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run [`schtasks /Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/schtasks#deleting-a-task) from [`[UninstallRun]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection):

```
[UninstallRun]
Filename: "schtasks"; Parameters: "/Delete /TN ""My Task"" /F"; Flags: runhidden
```

When the task does not exist, the command does nothing.

---

This is similar to [creating a task with Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12250151/850848#40037023).