# How to add a scheduled task with Inno Setup that runs hidden

Tags: windows, console-application, windows-task-scheduler

I've learned to add a task to the Windows 10 Task scheduler with Inno Setup ([article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12250151/how-to-add-a-scheduled-task-with-inno-setup?noredirect=1)).

```
Filename: "schtasks.exe"; Parameters: "/create /tn ""Greetings hourly"" /tr ""{app}\engine.exe -reprint"" /sc hourly /st 01:00 /f /NP"; Flags: shellexec
```

I use this to add a Delphi created console application, but when the task executes, the console window pops-up, because in the task properties there's a check in the "Run only when the user is logged on" checkbox. How can I create a task with the checkbox "Run whether the user is logged on or not" selected? If I add the /NP parameter, then the checkbox "Do not store password" is selected, but I don't want this.

I want to add a task that runs invisible and also regardless if the user is logged in or not.